# Showing density of overlapping features via transparency in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features, transparency-opacity, density, visualisation

Below is a famous map produced by the Facebook team, which shows the connections between their users. Where there are multiple overlapping features, the lines show more brightly, giving a clear indication of feature density.

[image]

How can this effect be emulated in ArcMap? For example, is it possible to show individual features with a set transparency, and stack these features with the transparency values accumulating to show where multiple features coincide?

The standard > Display > Transparency option applies to the whole layer equally.

The Facebook example uses light features on a dark background, but I'm also interested in dark features on a light background.

Comment: This is a more specific version of [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82806/how-do-i-make-a-map-where-overlapping-symbols-increase-opacity). QGIS is really good at it.

Comment: If you uncover an ArcGIS for Desktop solution there are at least three other questions that could benefit with being rolled up into one canonical Q&A and its duplicates: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/how-to-obtain-overlapping-semi-transparent-circles-effect,  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49145/displaying-transparent-overlapping-polygons-in-arcgis-for-desktop and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107608/overlapping-transparent-polygons-wont-darken

Comment: I have not actually done it, but I think the ArcGIS tool would be the Line Density tool in the Spatial Analyst Extension.  http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/How_Line_Density_works/009z00000012000000/

Comment: Did you ever look at or try the technique in http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/125189/115 that is link-only to https://luke-webber.github.io/polyline-heatmap/?  It seems to have come up again at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197844/arcgis-create-heatmap-of-line-features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some ArcGIS for Desktop answers have been provided at [Making map where overlapping symbols increase Opacity?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82806/making-map-where-overlapping-symbols-increase-opacity), I do not think there is a good solution for doing this in ArcMap.

I think this would be a good candidate for [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com) if you need it in ArcMap, but it looks like the functionality you are after may already be in ArcGIS Pro - see the ArcGIS blog post [Increase your transparency with ArcGIS Pro](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/11/19/increase-your-transparency-with-arcgis-pro/).